# vertical alignment within bootstrap column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

Trying to vertically center the text below. I've tried many of the solutions offered here but none have worked. Text always ends up at top of div. I have tried dozens of solutions.

```
<section id="services" class="services-section">
<div class="container">
<br />
<div class="row " style="background-color:#ffffff; margin:20px; padding:10px;">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 brown-background service-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/Siding.png" /></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <h2>Siding Wash</h2><p>Some home maintenance tasks are just right for the do-it-yourselfer, power washing your siding is not one of those tasks. A simple miscalculation could cause significant damage to your siding requiring an expensive repair. Phantom Power Washing has the know how to gently remove grim from your home’s exterior and reveal it’s original beauty.</p>
  </div>
  </div>

.services-section {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: #52402c;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the content you're trying to vertically centre in a div, and set its position to absolute and top padding to 50%. e.g.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" >
                    <div class="sidingCopy">
                    <h2>Siding Wash</h2><p>Some home maintenance tasks are just right for the do-it-yourselfer, power washing your siding is not one of those tasks. A simple miscalculation could cause significant damage to your siding requiring an expensive repair. Phantom Power Washing has the know how to gently remove grim from your home’s exterior and reveal it’s original beauty.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
.sidingCopy { position: absolute; padding: 50% 0 0 0; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I tried this, and while I can get the text content to move with this code, it doesn't respond dynamically - when in mobile view the columns stack and somehow the text from the column in question gets pushed into the next column and actually overlays it.

Comment: To clarify, is your problem that you don't want the two columns to stack? Or that you're unhappy with how the text overlays the next column?

Comment: The columns stack exactly the way I want them to. Yes, I can't have the text from one column overlaying the next. I'm using standard bootstrap columns. I don't understand why vertically centering text seems near impossible. You can check out how the page works here: www.phantompw.com

Comment: If you make a new class for the  

position: absolute; padding: 50% 0 0 0; 

...in your CSS, and wrap it in a media query so that it only goes into effect at screen widths wider than bootstrap's xs width, that should do the trick for this example. I'll edit my answer to include this.

Comment: Hmm - I am seeing it work in the various browsers I usually test in, so I'm at a loss! Which browser is it that you're still seeing the problem in?

Comment: Thanks a bunch. it's working now. Only change I made was Padding: 50% to Padding:13%.

Comment: Great! Someone may come along with a less hacky way - but glad it worked. 

ps: in the copy for that section there's a typo or two: I think 'grim' should be 'grime' and 'it's' should be 'its'